# Options to optimize lotus notes 8.5.X

Tags: performance, java, lotus-notes

Has anyone found actually useful optimization methods for the bulky, fat, eclipse giant, nuisance that is Lotus Notes 8.5?

I want it to be fast, and not eat up system resources like crazy while I run it ALL day (as it is my company's corporate mail / cal / scheduling solution).

I've tried various hacks for the JVM heap size (if I recall correctly). None really bring a performance improvement.

I have a dual core cpu, if that helps (I tried going the route of optimizing JAVA for 2 cores in hopes it would work, but seen no speed improvement).

Notes is just sooo bloated, anyone have any suggestions to optimize/mod this thing so it is more responsive and less of a resource hog.

**Note:**  I don't want to switch to the web version, or the standard stripped down versions, I am aware of those, I just cannot since we don't run those internally for the company.

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to say that the software that isn't there is fastest and most reliable (and poses the least security risk), and the best way to speed up Notes is to delete it.  Unfortunately, it isn't always an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets better with the latest versions...  8.5.1 is faster, and 8.5.2 should in turn be faster again?  Not quite the answer you were looking for, but an improvement...